# How do you do non-prompted installs in umake?

Tags: 16.04, automation, ubuntu-make

I'm trying to automate the installation of certain IDEs using umake. The command that I am currently trying is:

```
printf "~/.local/share/umake/ide/visual-studio-code\na\n" | umake ide visual-studio-code
printf "~/.local/share/umake/ide/idea-ultimate\n" | umake ide idea-ultimate
```

What this intends to do is specify the default install location and accept the license agreement. But this is unreliable and does not always work.

Is there a way to configure umake to skip (or automatically accept) prompts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that there's a help command which explains this. It's a bit harder to find than usual:

```
umake ide -h visual-studio-code
```

which returns

```
umake ide visual-studio-code [-h] [-r] [--accept-license] [destdir]
```

The output depends per IDE, so each IDE that you want to install has it's own configuration parameters. And from here, it can be determined whether it's possible to skip prompts.